# Print PDF in android, works on 2nd time on specific devices

Tags: java, android, pdf, printing, webview

Im trying to create PDF printer on Android for webview. I prepared view, and print manager, everything works Perfectly on my phone. After all, my friends with samsung and huawei find out - they have blank print view on first open. On second one - everyghing is ok. When i use Xiaomi or LG, everyghing works on first time. 
Im looking for solution on Stack and my case is not about 0.0 width and High. Deos anyone had simmilar problem with print webview in Android? Is there any problems with touchwiz or something like this?

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing similar issue, Webview inside customview does not work in samsung and huawei, but works in xiaomi. Have you managed to solve this issue?